# Row span without affecting other rows

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to figure out how to display a div over multiple rows without affecting the height of others div elements using the same rows.

Here is an example:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

#navigation {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  background-color: #CCC;
  grid-row: 1;
}

#hero {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  background-color: #BBB;
  grid-row: 2;
}

#left1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row: 3;
  background-color: #AAA;
}

#left2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row: 4;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

#right {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  grid-row: 3/5;
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="navigation">NAVIGATION</div>
  <div id="hero">HERO IMAGE</div>
  <div id="left1">Left1</div>
  <div id="left2">Left2</div>
  <div id="right">Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right
    Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right
    Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right
    Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right
    Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right
    Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right
    Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right </div>
</div>
```

The div called `#right` is always going to be much longer than `#left1` and `#left2`. If I put them aside, `#right` will increase the height of `#left1` and `#left2` and I would like to avoid that.

I could fix the problem by defining row heights in the grid definition but I'm never 100% sure how big `#left1` and `#left2` will be.

Example:

```
grid-template-rows: 50px 400px 300px 300px auto;
```

That works when dimensions are not exceeding those values but what I need is a "fit to content" approach for all div elements without creating dependencies between them.

Is that achievable with grid?

Thanks

Comment: `#right {grid-row: 3 / 6;}` ?

Comment: ah-ah, that's a simple solution, it works but why? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rows are set to `auto` height.

```
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr)); <--  ignored; overruled
  grid-template-rows: auto; <-- winning rule
}
```

This means that the height of the first row (explicit grid) will be determined by content height.

The height of the remaining rows (implicit grid) will also be determined by the content height, because the default setting for [`grid-auto-rows`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-tracks) is also `auto`.

It also means that a CSS Grid rule goes into effect: *Free space among grid tracks with `auto` sizing is divided equally among them.*

> § [11.8. Stretch `auto`
> Tracks](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#algo-stretch)
>
> This step expands tracks that have an `auto` max track sizing function
> by dividing any remaining positive, definite free space equally
> amongst them. If the free space is indefinite, but the grid container
> has a definite `min-width/height`, use that size to calculate the free
> space for this step instead.

So when `#left1` and `#left2` share the same tracks with `#right1`, the free space (created in the left areas because the right area is taller) is distributed equally among the left areas.

But if the `#right1` area is made to span into an empty, undefined row (let's say, from `grid-row: 3/5` to `grid-row: 3/6`) it's no longer bound to the `#left1` and `#left2` tracks, and the `auto` stretch algorithm no longer applies.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

#navigation {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  background-color: #CCC;
  grid-row: 1;
}

#hero {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  background-color: #BBB;
  grid-row: 2;
}

#left1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row: 3;
  background-color: #AAA;
}

#left2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row: 4;
  background-color: #DDD;
}

#right {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 13;
  /* grid-row: 3/5; */
  grid-row: 3/6;   /* new */
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="navigation">NAVIGATION</div>
  <div id="hero">HERO IMAGE</div>
  <div id="left1">Left1</div>
  <div id="left2">Left2</div>
  <div id="right">Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right
    Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right
    Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right
    Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right
    Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right
    Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right
    Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right </div>
</div>
```

---

*In all honesty, I'm about 60% sure this answer is fully correct and 80% sure it's partially correct. Mostly because spanning `#right` to a new row still creates a new (third) area in the left column which is also, presumably, sized to `auto`, like its two siblings above.*

*So why doesn't "#left3" behave like `#left1` and `#left2`? (i.e., equal distribution of free space)*

*I'm thinking it's because "#left3" is empty (HTML) and undefined (CSS).*

*In any case, the spec language isn't entirely clear to me and the [Track Sizing Algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#algo-track-sizing) is much more complex than the [Stretch `auto` Tracks](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#algo-stretch) section cited above. So there may be other factors in play.*

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty interesting! I'll have to think about the rows I want to add below in order to avoid any interferences